# Why can't intl.so find libicu?

Tags: php

On macOS 13.6 (Ventura) I have ICU installed in `/usr/local` and configured PHP with `--prefix=/usr/local/php8x` (for php80, php81, and so on).

The configure script has no problem finding libicu, but at runtime I get the dreaded error `Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so' .... Library not loaded: libicuio.XX.dylib`.

It looks like the shared object has no awareness of where the library is located once the runtime has been built.

I can fix this by setting the environment variable `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` to `usr/local/lib` but I don't like this solution.

What is the proper way to ensure that the shared object searches the original library paths?